# Qt designer via homebrew

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I installed Qt5 via homebrew, but I didn't find the designer. 
I also installed qtcreator (`Caskroom/cask/qt-creator`) but the designer icon is grayed out:

[image: grayed out]

Any ideas where I can find the designer?

p.s. Does this means that designer is going to retire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you double-click on a .ui-File (within Creator), the Designer will become active.

Or you need to add a Qt-Designer-Form with the wizard if you have no ui file yet.

Answer (score 2):

otherise you can open Qt Designer alone (not inside Qt Creator) by doing `open -a Designer`