# Installing PyQt5 (incl. Qt Designer) on macOS (Sierra)

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pyqt

Can anyone explain (or point me to instructions on) how to install PyQt5 for macOS (Python 3.6) that **includes the QT Designer application**?

I've been searching the internet for the past few days and I just cannot get it to install.

I've tried the manual installation but get stuck on the `--qmake` and I've tried `pip install PyQt5` but this does not have the Qt Designer.

**Edit:**

This is not a duplicate of [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090739/pyqt5-how-to-start-the-designer), the previous question talks to a) windows operating system and b) provides the solution of using `pip install pyqt5-tools` which is not available for macOS

Comment: Link you provided speaks to using `pip install pyqt5-tools`. I've tried this and get `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5-tools (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyqt5-tools`

Comment: I've just successfully installed it the same way.

Comment: On mac?!! Why can't mine seem to find anything...

Comment: On PC. So that could be a specific bug for mac.

Comment: Ah! Yea I got it installed on my work PC using that same method, but now trying mac. Cannot find anything that works...

Comment: @Braden. On osx, it might be necessary to install qt-creator, which includes qt-designer as an integrated component. I don't know whether qt-designer is available as a stand-alone app on osx, but I don't see why it shouldn't be. If you have installed qt5 correctly, I have seen some mac users say that `open -a Designer-qt5` will run it. But I am not a mac user myself, so I cannot test that.

Comment: @ekhumoro Tried this but the 'designer' tab in the creator was faded out and not accessible. Will try the command line when I get into the office.

Comment: @Braden. That's normal - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35118056/qt-designer-via-homebrew).

Answer (score 3):

I used `brew install Qt5` and then `open -a Designer` will start Qt Designer. After that I installed PyQt5 with `pip install pyqt5`.

Answer (score 0):

The QT Designer is a separate tool that uses PyQt widgets. It is not included in the PyQt5 framework which is why you won't find a PyQt5 library that comes with it. In order to acquire it you must install Qt Designer separately from your PyQt installation.

Once you have installed PyQt5, install PyQt5Designer like so:
pip install PyQt5Designer

If pip doesn't work for you I would recommend trying another package manager such as:

- Homebrew https://brew.sh/
- Anaconda https://www.anaconda.com/download/#maco
- Macports https://www.macports.org/

If neither of these package managers work try via the stand-alone installer from this link: https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download

Hope this helps.