# Install pyqt5-tools on macOS

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I have installed PyQt5 with pip and used it successfully with Python v3 and run through a tutorial.

In looking at tutorials for Qt Designer I see instructions to use pip install [pyqt5-tools](https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/) but it appears that there are only wheels available for Win32.

How can I use Qt Designer or some equivalent tool on the Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Try using QT-creator for MAC, it includes QT designer

You can find it from here: https://www.qt.io/download

If you have any problems accusing QT-designer from within creator, try this [Qt designer via homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35118056/qt-designer-via-homebrew)

Answer (score 0):

try install pyqt5-tools~=5.15

source: https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/